# How to select number of hidden layers and number of memory cells in LSTM?

Tags: python, lstm

How to select number of hidden layers and number of memory cells in LSTM?
I want make LSTM model about classification.

```py
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(44000,32))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of memory cells can be set by passing in `input_length` parameter to your embedding layer, as it is defined by the length of your input sequences. This is optional and can be inferred when training data is provided.

You can increase the number of hidden LSTM layers by simply adding more. You need to set `return_sequences=True` to maintain the temporal dimension for your intermediate LSTM layers, however, ie,

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(44000,32))  # 32-dim encoding is pretty small
model.add(LSTM(32), return_sequences=True)
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

gives two LSTM layers.

There is a pretty comprehensive guide to using RNNs for text classification in the Tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/text_classification_rnn).